# Is there a drag and drop plugin for JavaFX similar to swing for eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, drag

I installed JRE 8 and am using Eclipse.

The first thing is that I get no JavaFX project suggestion when creating a new project, although it says everywhere that there should be.

Secondly, I was wondering if there is a drag and drop plugin available for Eclipse that would allow me to learn JavaFX basics a lot faster. I've been looking around but oddly all the articles seem outdated (2012 and before).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [e(fx)clipse project](https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse), which provides tooling and runtime support. If all you want Eclipse for is for JavaFX, then you can download an e(fx)clipse build directly; if you want to install e(fx)clipse into an existing Eclipse installation, see https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html

Comment: Seems like what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, is there a way to get the XML code to java code? Because I'm not knowledgeable with XML, and doesn't help much with learning how javaFX works in java.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn JavaFX 8 I can recommend the tutorial from [codemakery.ch](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part1/)

Also I'm not quite sure what you mean by Drag and Drop Plug-In, if you want to use a Designer the Plug-In e(fx)clipse together with Scene  Builder 2.0 worked great for me. The only thing is that your getting fxml and not java code out of it, but thats just what you prefer. (The plugin could also fix  your issue with the project)

Comment: Seems like what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For javaFX drag and drop install scenebuilder application from http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/ and open the java FXML file in scenebuilder.